# Sorting by nested integer value with jq

Tags: json, sorting, key, jq

I have a JSON object of objects:

```
{
  "lungCancerCellLines": {
    "componentIndex": 11,
    "active": true,
    "longName": "Lung cancer cell lines",
    "filenameKey": "lungCancerCellLines",
    "color": "#8CC63F"
  },
  "naturalKillerCells": {
    "componentIndex": 1,
    "active": true,
    "longName": "Natural killer cells",
    "filenameKey": "naturalKillerCells",
    "color": "#BB2DD4"
  },
  "respiratoryMuscular": {
    "componentIndex": 12,
    "active": true,
    "longName": "Respiratory / muscular",
    "filenameKey": "respiratoryMuscular",
    "color": "#DDE223"
  },
  "cerebellarHemisphere": {
    "componentIndex": 14,
    "active": true,
    "longName": "Cerebellar hemisphere",
    "filenameKey": "cerebellarHemisphere",
    "color": "#2E97BC"
  },
  "bCells": {
    "componentIndex": 2,
    "active": true,
    "longName": "B cells",
    "filenameKey": "bCells",
    "color": "#E6009B"
  },
  ...,
  "cd34PlusProgenitor": {
    "componentIndex": 8,
    "active": true,
    "longName": "CD34+ progenitor",
    "filenameKey": "cd34PlusProgenitor",
    "color": "#ED2024"
  }
}
```

I would like to write a JSON object in (ascending) order of `componentIndex`.

Based on previous Stack Overflow questions and answers, I have tried the following statements:

```
jq -s 'sort_by(.[].componentIndex)' in.json > out.v1.json
```

And:

```
jq -s 'sort_by(.[].componentIndex|tonumber)' in.json > out.v2.json
```

The files `out.v1.json` and `out.v2.json` are identical to `in.json` in presented order.

What is the correct `jq` statement to provide the nested objects in the desired sort order?

The real question I am asking is how to extract the value of `color` keys in the order provided by the integers in `componentIndex`. But as a first step, it looks like I need to solve how to sort on integer values with `jq`. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to write a JSON object in (ascending) order of `componentIndex`.

> What is the correct `jq` statement to provide the nested objects in the desired sort order?

You can't (reliably) sort object fields (while retaining them as an object) because an object's order of fields is not part of the information conveyed by the JSON encoding. There is, of course, an implicit order in the actual representation of the document as a character stream, but this just happens to be the one you see. Any other ordering of object fields is still considered the same document, and any JSON processor may just disregard or even re-arrange that order without giving notice.

That said, you can, however, trick jq into generating exactly that ordering for the object by first turning it into an array representation using `to_entries` (which preserves the keys), then sorting that array (using `.value` to access its values), and then re-assembling the object using the inverse filter `from_entries` (which, as of the current version of jq at least, happens to reflect the input array's order). But keep in mind that this ordering is not guaranteed to be preserved or even interpreted as such by the next processor (including future versions of jq).

```bash
jq 'to_entries | sort_by(.value.componentIndex) | from_entries'
```

```json
{
  "naturalKillerCells": {
    "componentIndex": 1,
    "active": true,
    "longName": "Natural killer cells",
    "filenameKey": "naturalKillerCells",
    "color": "#BB2DD4"
  },
  "bCells": {
    "componentIndex": 2,
    "active": true,
    "longName": "B cells",
    "filenameKey": "bCells",
    "color": "#E6009B"
  },
  "cd34PlusProgenitor": {
    "componentIndex": 8,
    "active": true,
    "longName": "CD34+ progenitor",
    "filenameKey": "cd34PlusProgenitor",
    "color": "#ED2024"
  },
  "lungCancerCellLines": {
    "componentIndex": 11,
    "active": true,
    "longName": "Lung cancer cell lines",
    "filenameKey": "lungCancerCellLines",
    "color": "#8CC63F"
  },
  "respiratoryMuscular": {
    "componentIndex": 12,
    "active": true,
    "longName": "Respiratory / muscular",
    "filenameKey": "respiratoryMuscular",
    "color": "#DDE223"
  },
  "cerebellarHemisphere": {
    "componentIndex": 14,
    "active": true,
    "longName": "Cerebellar hemisphere",
    "filenameKey": "cerebellarHemisphere",
    "color": "#2E97BC"
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/sSwY0ZgjnaW)

---

> The real question I am asking is how to extract the value of `color` keys in the order provided by the integers in `componentIndex`.

For that, you really just need to convert the object into a regular (you don't need the keys) array of objects using `map(.)` or `[.[]]`, then sort it using `sort_by(.componentIndex)` (note that `.componentIndex` is already a number, so `.componentIndex|tonumber` won't make a difference here), and extract from its items the fields you're interested in:

```bash
jq -r 'map(.) | sort_by(.componentIndex)[].color'
```

```
#BB2DD4
#E6009B
#ED2024
#8CC63F
#DDE223
#2E97BC
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/OIPjMurbs2F)

Comment: I understand that objects are unordered internally. I am definitely interested in presenting the object in a specific order, however. Thanks for answering my question as written!